# 'execute windows batch command' not working in jenkins freestyle project

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins freestyle project. At build steps I selected, 'execute windows batch command' and given command as timeout 10

When I build, job failed with reason "'timeout' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file"

The same problem with ping google.com command as well

Am I missing something in the command?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please verify that you have defined the correct agent label for the job to run.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it on built-in node (jenkins controller) which is windows machine

Comment: Both timeout and ping are external executables, not built-ins. Maybe your %PATH% is messed up? Run `echo %PATH%` from a build step to check.

Comment: Thank you, That worked! I have to add path 'C:\Windows\System32' at 'built-in node > configuration  > environment variables. I had assumed that these commands gets actually executed in my built-in node machine command prompt (windows). Is my understanding wrong? and why? Can you help?